# How to improve the text clarity in html?

Tags: css

In my html page the text is looked not that much of smooth and sharp,
any idea to overcome that..

Comment: Can you at least show us an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Give more data which browser, which OS and if ClearType is enabled... etc etc. This has to do with font rendering. Doesn't have to do so much with HTML/CSS in the first place (if at all).

Comment: Font family : Gill Sans, Arial, Verdana;
 Size : 18 pt;
 Color : e2189e;

<span>Welcome</span>

just this is what am using..

Comment: You mention that the text is not smooth and sharp? What are you comparing it to? Apple related products like to use anti-aliasing for keeping true to a typeface. You are using "Gill Sans" I don't see that as a common font, I don't have it and your styling would revert to Arial for me. Is your span inheriting any other styles at all? 18pt is rather large "size:" is not a css property did you mean "font-size" or is this CSS just wrong? Your line height will mess with font that big too.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some guidelines:

- Use common font such as **Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, etc**
- If possibly give your text `line-height`
- Choose correct colors with respect to page's background
- Choose accessible fonts

**Resources:**

- **[Web-Safe Fonts for Your Site](http://www.theinternetdigest.net/archive/websafefonts.html)**
- **[CSS for Accessibility](http://24ways.org/2007/css-for-accessibility)**

Answer (score -1):

We need:

1. Example (simplified) html.
2. Browser being used.
3. Screen shot showing problem.

Then it can be diagnosed.

Comment: Put this as a comment rather than an answer.